# Select min date value and calculate date value?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table called **"SUMMARYDATA"** which has columns **"STATUSIN,STATUSOUT,LATECOME"** and I want to select min value on column "STATUSIN". And make a condition: `IF MIN(STATUSIN) > "08.00 AM" Then LATECOME = MIN(STATUSIN) - "08.00 AM"`. How to select min date value? And how to calculate `MIN(STATUSIN) - "08.00 AM"`?

This is my code to display data from database:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrSUMMARYDATA" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>IN</th>
                        <th>OUT</th>
                        <th>LATECOME</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("STATUSIN") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("STATUSOUT") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("LATECOME") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

This is my code on backend:

```
     private void BindSUMMARYDATARptr()
    {
        String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MANHOURConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SUMMARYDATA", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dtDaily = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dtDaily);

                    rptrSUMMARYDATA.DataSource = dtDaily;
                    rptrSUMMARYDATA.DataBind();
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this..

```
  SELECT  STATUSIN,STATUSOUT, CASE WHEN CAST(STATUSIN AS TIME) > CAST('08:00:00' AS TIME) 
           THEN CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(s, -28800 ,STATUSIN), 108)  END AS LATECOME 
  FROM SUMMARYDATA
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, it's work:) but how to updated the value in column `'LATECOME'`?

Comment: just assign the LATECome value to the column

Comment: @DeaAnanda, where is `MIN(STATUSIN)`?

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla oh ya i'm sorry, i'm forgot about the `MIN(STATUSIN)`, it's don't work when there is more data value in `STATUSIN`. i said it works because when i run, my data value in `STATUSIN` just 1

Comment: purpose of using MIN(STATUSIN)?

Comment: because there is multiple date value in the column @Mano

Answer (score 1):

Get the `MIN` from `datatable` and use `DateTime.Subtract`

```
var minIN = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.AsEnumerable().Min(row => row["IN"]));
Console.WriteLine($"LATECOME {minIN.Subtract(minIN.Date + new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0))}");
```

> Note: `AsEnumerable` is part of `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`. Install this package from nuget

To Update directly in Database (I would not recommend this, unless it is absolutely needed)

```
UPDATE SUMMARYDATA 
  SET LATECOME =  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(s,DATEADD(HOUR, 8, CAST(CAST((select MIN(STATUSIN) from SUMMARYDATA)  AS DATE) AS DATETIME)),(select MIN(STATUSIN) from SUMMARYDATA)) > 0 THEN
  (CONVERT(TIME,(select MIN(STATUSIN) from SUMMARYDATA)-DATEADD(HOUR, 8, CAST(CAST((select MIN(STATUSIN) from SUMMARYDATA)  AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))) ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, i've been try that code, but the value still not appear in `LATECOME` column. how to save the value in column 'LATECOME'?

Comment: I've been try the updated code, it's work, but it's not the output that i meant. That should have a condition : `IF MIN(STATUSIN) > "08.00 AM"` Then `LATECOME = MIN(STATUSIN) - "08.00 AM"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me:), i've been try that code. i have already some data that have date value > 8 PM. but why the column 'LATECOME' still NULL?

Comment: @DeaAnanda, soon after you find `MIN(STATUSIN)` the others having more will be ignorned. I guess you need check the requirement again. for me this condition of `MIN(STATUSIN)` doesnt make any sense

Comment: the condition of `MIN(STATUSIN)` to filter minimum date value, because there is multiple data date value in the column

Answer (score 1):

```
select DATEADD(minute, -iif(CAST(STATUSIN as time) > CAST('08:00' as time), DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST('08:00' as time),CAST(STATUSIN as time)) ,0) , STATUSIN) as LATECOME
from SUMMARYDATA
```

Comment: update query :
update SUMMARYDATA set LATECOME=  DATEADD(minute, -iif(CAST(STATUSIN as time) > CAST('08:00' as time), DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST('08:00' as time),CAST(STATUSIN as time)) ,0) , STATUSIN)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select STATUSIN,STATUSOUT,case when CAST(STATUSIN as time) > CAST('08:00' as time) then 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST('08:00' as time),CAST(STATUSIN as time)) 
end as LATECOME from test;
```

Comment: Thank yo for helping me, it's work. but, how to show the value in datetime value? i meant show the (hh:mm:ss) and how to update the value into column `LATECOME`